# Setup Puppy to save to HDD

Tags: live-usb, puppy-linux

Puppy Linux has a feature that will let you save the session to HDD when run from a Live-USB.

> BOOT FROM USB - While booted from CD or DVD, install Puppy to USB and use it for booting (see Setup in the menu for the installer). You can then tell Puppy at shutdown to save to the same USB drive, or to your hard disk.

http://puppylinux.org/main/How%20NOT%20to%20install%20Puppy.htm

However, when I shut mine down, I did not get a prompt for any such thing.

How can I activate this functionality at runtime?